# In MS Word, Opening a .txt file gives "Is not a valid single file web page" error

Tags: microsoft-word, webarchive

I have an email header stored in a .txt file.
An automated process opens the file in Ms Word 2016.

Word gives "Is not a valid single file web page" error.

Obviously word is sniffing the file, it looks like a mime document, word incorrectly decides it's a web archive file, and tried to open it as such.
This fails, as it obviously isn't a web archive file.

Is there any way to switch off this behavior in word?

Comment: does it display the same behavior if you open it from within word using the "open" feature?

Comment: @Blaine: Yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having typed the question I subsequently submitted rephrased web searches, and got [Turning off HTML Conversions](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T006275_Turning_Off_HTML_Conversions.html), give two options.

One can either find the "Confirm File Format Conversion On Open" option in
**Options->Advanced->General**
and switch it on, this will not work for me, as there's no user to confirm the action, or . . .

> ... you can remove the HTML file filter used by Word. This is done
>   by running the Word Setup program and then making sure the HTML filter
>   is removed from the system. (You do this by making sure the option is
>   explicitly NOT selected in the Setup program.)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.